Unexpected store exception, Rebooted but now Windows won’t boot. Stuck at manufacturer logo
I’ll explain the situation So yesterday I got a blue screen of dead, with the error code UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION. I tried to look online for quite a bit but I can’t seem to find a solution, even YouTube videos are pretty much useless. The only thing I can do from the screen is boot BIOS from holding F2 key while turning on and accessing boot menu from holding ESC still while turning on. If this helps, if I press caps lock key, it shows that it’s on. Also, I can’t access the recovery mode, as windows is not starting. I’d like to know what I can do, also I wouldn’t want to reset my computer or hard drive.
I was thinking maybe creating a media installation tool for USB and booting to that try to repair, but if there’s other things I should try let me know. I had took a picture of the BSOD. Also, as said in the title, it had rebooted with no problems, as in the progress went from 0% to 100% naturally them rebooted, but got stuck to the ASUS(manufacturer) logo since. There’s no loading circle, spinning circle… just the logo. I also had a system tweak that gave more information on a bsod, I forgot what, but these are additional that were shown if they can help? 0xFFFFDA8B2AC55000 0xFFFFA30D28A05F20 0x0000000000000002 0x0000000000000000
Ultimately, my hard drive shows up in BIOS and the boot entry “Windows Boot Manager” does too. I can’t enter recovery mode as windows doesn’t boot.
